# MySQL WHERE with OR conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

Is there any shortcut for this on MySQL?

```
WHERE month = 'January' OR month = 'January' OR month = 'February' OR month = 'March' OR month = 'April' OR month = 'May' OR month = 'June'
```

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work,

```
WHERE month = '(January || February || March || April || May || June)'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
WHERE `month` IN ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June');
```

in php

```
$months = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June');
$sql .= "WHERE `month` IN ('".implode("', '", $months)."')";
```

In addition to this: When storing dates, such as months, it's better to store them as integer values, instead of strings. This will help with performance, I18N, and if you use int values, you can use BETWEEN

```
WHERE `month` BETWEEN 1 AND 6
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @Ben you've answered my question more than I asked for. It helps a lot :)

Comment: one more question, do "1" and "6" included in query? or just the value in "between" of them?

Comment: @ivory-santos it's included. Check out the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between for more details

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use [`IN`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) clause for that. Like this:

```
WHERE month in ('January','February','March','April','May','June')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN` clause.

```
WHERE `month` IN ('January','February','March','April', 'May','June')
```

see the backticks in `month`? It escapes the keyword *month* since there exist built-in function called **[Month( )](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)**

Comment: not necessary. function names do not count as reserved words, since they'd only be interpreted as function if they had `()` as well. an unquoted `month` by itself means nothing special to mysql.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for that. just to make it a habit of using `backtick` :D

Comment: @John It's not a bad habit to have

Answer (score 2):

Try..

```
WHERE month IN ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June');
```